# How to decrypt the string encrypted with ENCRYPT function

Tags: mysql

The documentation tells how to encrypt using ENCRYPT()

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt

Example

```
mysql> SELECT ENCRYPT('hello');
    -> 'VxuFAJXVARROc'
```

But how can we decrypt it.. Because there is no DECRYPT() function.

PS:
I am not talking about AES_DECRYPT(), AES_ENCRYPT(), DES_DECRYPT(), DES_ENCRYPT()

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

ENCRYPT is, unfortunately, incorrectly named. If you're using PHP, it's equivalent to the [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function with CRYPT_STD_DES, which also calls the system crypt in the same manner. It is not actually encryption however, it's a one-way hash. There is no (definitive) means to reverse it but it is susceptible to dictionary look ups, which can be done quite quickly. Note, it is pretty ancient and weak, and should not be used for anything that you hope to keep remotely secure.

Comment: So I should use AES_ENCRYPT() instead?

Comment: Maybe? I do not know what your requirements are.

Comment: Storing short strings in order to retrieve them later

Comment: That doesn't help. What's the string? A password? Why does it need to be encrypted? Do you actually need to reverse the string or is it sufficient to simply compare it to another encrypted string?